# D3 Redraw Brush

Tags: d3.js, brush

I have a problem that I haven't been able to solve for a number of weeks. I'm working on a modified version of this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 I've defined the brush initially so it has a brush extent between 0.5 and 0.8.

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .extent([0.5, 0.8])
    .on("brush", brushed);
```

The brush selection shows up (on the context graph) in the correct location, but the initial view of the focus area is still set to the extent of the entire data set (and not to the clipping area of the brush). I've read that defining the brush doesn't automatically force a redraw of the area, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the view of the focus area automatically scale to the brush extents. Can someone please provide some input on this?

**Update 1**
I currently have a function called Brushed which does the following:

```
function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select("path").attr("d", Light_area);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  Light_line_overlay.select("path").attr("d", Light_area);

  rules.select(".y.grid").call(make_x_axis_light()
          .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
          .tickFormat("")
      );

  var xx0=brush.x()(brush.extent()[0]);
  var xx1=brush.x()(brush.extent()[1]);

  brushfill.attr("x", xx0);
  brushfill.attr("width", xx1-xx0);
}
```

It's slightly different from the example... because I've been modifying it to do different things from the base example.  However, the first comment suggests that I should just call this brushed function after declaring the brush (see first post).  However, calling this function doesn't do anything (or at least, it doesn't update the focus area to the extents of the brush).  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for answering this two years late but I just ran in to the same situation and this was the only resource I found on the topic. I was able to figure it out, so hopefully this will help anybody else who stumbles upon it.

The code in the original question was almost all the way there, it just didn't have the right scaling on the extent initialization.

The data I'm using is an array of objects with a `ts` key (which is epoch milliseconds) that I use for my `x` values.

```
// These are needed for the brush construction to know how to scale
x2.domain(x.domain());
y2.domain(y.domain());

// Pick out the ~50% and ~80% marks from the data
var N = data.length;
var cx0 = new Date(data[Math.floor(N*0.50)].ts);
var cx1 = new Date(data[Math.floor(N*0.80)].ts);

// Construct with that extent, which will leave the
// context box started in the correct position.
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
                  .x(x2)
                  .extent([cx0, cx1])
                  .on("brush", brushed)
;

// This is just the original brushed example 
function brushed() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    focus.select(".area").attr("d", line);
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}

...

var focus = svg.append("g")
               .attr("class", "focus")
               .attr("transform",
                     "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
;

// Now that focus is defined we can manually update it
brushed();
```

I actually kept the call to `brushed` at the very end of the setup, just to keep things pretty, but the point here was just to illustrate that once `focus` is defined you can call `brushed` to do whatever updates you want there.

Ultimately it seems your main issue was getting the right type for the extent. Using `[0.5, 0.8]` worked on initialization, but if you check whenever `brushed` is called from actually sliding the focus around with the mouse, `brush.extent()` will be `[Date(), Date()]`. And that makes sense, since we're passing that extent to `x.domain`. So this sets up all the scaling before initializing the brush, so that the initialization extent can be a `Date`, then everything else is gravy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform actions similar to the ones of the brushed function whenever your brush extent is changed programmatically. Resize the x.domain, refresh the view.

```
function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select("path").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, consider providing some code example.